# ¿Cómo generar un pdf con TCPDF, de modo que se abra automaticamente una vez generado?

Tags: jquery, pdf

Estoy utilizando TCPDF, el cual me permite crear un pdf, pero el tema es que cuando se genera el pdf, se despliega la pantalla para guardarlo. Luego debo ir al directorio donde quedó guardado el pdf y abrirlo. Este comportamiento no es el que requiero. Lo que requiero es que cuando se genere el pdf, éste se abra en forma automática y luego se pueda enviar a imprimir o guardar.

Existe alguna forma de configurar TCPDF de modo que se comporte del modo que he explicado? Estoy bajo Jquery. Gracias.

Lo que tengo implementado hasta ahora es:

```
<?php  
$v1 = $_GET['respuesta'];
 function busca_datos($v)  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "cuenta", "pass", "basedato");  
      $sql = "SELECT id_cliente, cedula, nombres, tel, dir FROM clientes ORDER BY id_cliente ASC";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {       
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td>'.$row["id_cliente"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["cedula"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["nombres"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["tel"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["dir"].'</td>  
                     </tr> 
                     <tr>
                        <td>Parametro1</td>
                        <td>'.$v.'</td>
                     </tr> 
                          ';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["create_pdf"]))  
 {  
      require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');           
      header('Content-type: application/pdf');
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Export HTML Table data to PDF using TCPDF in PHP");  
      $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
      $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
      $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
      $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
      $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
      $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
      $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);  
      $obj_pdf->AddPage();  
      $content = '';  
      $content .= '  
      <h3 align="center">Ejemplo de generacion pdf</h3><br /><br />  
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">  
           <tr>  
              <th>Cliente</th>  
              <th>Cedula</th>  
              <th>Nombre</th>  
              <th>Telefono</th>
              <th>Direccion</th>
           </tr>
      ';  
      $content .= busca_datos($v1);  
      $content .= '</table>';  
      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
      $nombre='Archivo_'.$v1.'_'.date("d-m-Y H-i-s").'.pdf';
      $obj_pdf->Output($nombre, 'D');      
 }   
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Exportando a PDF desde PHP</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">            
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Ejemplo de generacion pdf</h3><br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th>Cliente</th>  
                               <th>Cedula</th>  
                               <th>Nombre</th>  
                               <th>Telefono</th>
                               <th>Direccion</th>
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     echo busca_datos($v1);  
                     ?>  
                     </table>  
                     <br />  
                     <form method="post">  
                          <input type="submit" name="create_pdf" class="btn btn-danger" value="Crear PDF" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Como se puede ver, el código tiene dos partes. La primera genera una tabla en pantalla. La segunda, dibuja la misma tabla en el pdf que se genera.

Comment: Trabajas con Jquery para generarlo o PHP¡?

Comment: La invocación del archivo php que genera el pdf se hace desde jquery, pero la lógica de generación del pdf se hace en el php.

Comment: @JuncoFuerte Y podes visualizar en tu navegador web, sin utilizar plugins, si no una librería de mozilla (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/). Es compatible con los demás navegadores. Es muy fácil de usar y soluciona tu problema. Yo lo utilizo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para la descarga podes usar:

```
$pdf->Output("Plan General Trabajo.pdf", 'D');
```

Colocar el encabezado:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

Y poder visualizar en tu navegador web, sin utilizar plugins, si no una librería de [mozilla](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/). 
Es compatible con los demás navegadores.

Y en la url en tu javascript escribís.

```
pdf/web/viewer.html?pdf=hola.pdf
```

Para obtener la librería PDF.js

Obs:

- Se utiliza Debian Jessie de 64 bits.
- Se asume que se tiene instalado Nodejs y NPM

Entramos a la terminal y tecleamos lo siguiente:

```
cd /var/www/html
git clone git://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js.git pdfjs
cd pdfjs
npm install
sudo npm install --global gulp-cli
node make generic
```

Obs:

- Con los pasos anteriores se creará la carpeta build en la cual encontraremos el archivo PDF.js el cual nos servirá para cargar nuestros PDF desde la Web.
  Dentro del proyecto compilado existe la carpeta generic. Toda esa carpeta copia en la raíz de tu proyecto.
- PDF.js está diseñado para ejecutarse desde un servicio web (ejemplo Apache2).
- Si te complica obtener la librería lista para usar, podes [descargar](http://proyectosbeta.net/Arhivos%20del%20Blog/varios/generic.zip).

Ahora el codigo:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <head>
           <title>Exportando a PDF desde PHP</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      </head>
      <body onload="">
           <br /><br />
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">
                <h3 align="center">Ejemplo de generacion pdf</h3><br />
                <div class="table-responsive">
                     <table class="table table-bordered">
                          <tr>
                               <th>Cliente</th>
                               <th>Cedula</th>
                               <th>Nombre</th>
                               <th>Telefono</th>
                               <th>Direccion</th>
                          </tr>
                     <?php
                         //echo busca_datos($v1);
                     ?>
                     </table>
                     <br />
                     <a href="generic/web/viewer.html?file=../../get_document.php" target="_blank">Crear PDF</a>
                </div>
           </div>
      </body>
 </html>
```

get_document.php

```
<?php
$v1 = $_GET['respuesta'];
 function busca_datos($v)
 {
      $output = '';
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "cuenta", "pass", "basedato");
      $sql = "SELECT id_cliente, cedula, nombres, tel, dir FROM clientes ORDER BY id_cliente ASC";
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      $output .= '<tr>
                          <td>'.$row["id_cliente"].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row["cedula"].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row["nombres"].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row["tel"].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row["dir"].'</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Parametro1</td>
                        <td>'.$v.'</td>
                     </tr>
                          ';
      }
      return $output;
 }

require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
$obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$obj_pdf->SetTitle("Export HTML Table data to PDF using TCPDF in PHP");
$obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
$obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);
$obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
$obj_pdf->AddPage();
$content = '';
$content .= '
<h3 align="center">Ejemplo de generacion pdf</h3><br /><br />
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
     <tr>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Cedula</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Telefono</th>
        <th>Direccion</th>
     </tr>
';
$content .= busca_datos($v1);
$content .= '</table>';
$obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);
$nombre='Archivo_'.$v1.'_'.date("d-m-Y H-i-s").'.pdf';
$obj_pdf->Output($nombre, 'D');
```

Con todo eso[image: Resultado]

Comment: Gracias josego. Te comento que puse en el cuerpo de la pregunta el código de lo que tengo implementado. Incorporé la sugerencia:

$obj_pdf->Output($nombre, 'D'); 

Con respecto de lo que indicas sobre agregar header, lo incorporé después de  if(isset($_POST["create_pdf"]))  ; no sé si está correcto el lugar en donde coloqué esa sentencia; me puedes confirmar por favor.

Finalmente, con respecto de tu última sugerencia, no comprendo donde debe ir; me puedes aclarar por favor. Gracias.

Comment: @JuncoFuerte mejore la respuesta con ejemplo funcionando. Cualquier cosa avisame, que me funciona en podes ver el pdf generado sin que se descargue. Solo debes de hacer click en el link de Crear PDF

Answer (score 1):

De stackoverflow en ingles la siguiente recomendación: 
Intenta:

```
$pdf->Output('name.pdf', 'O');
```

o

```
$pdf->Output('name.pdf', 'I');
```

Si lo anterior no funciona, utiliza la función `header()`

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
```

Después de usar la función `header()`, utiliza `echo` al contenido del **PDF** que creaste.

Según la documentación:

> - D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given    by name.
> - F: save to a local server file with the name given by name.
> - S: return the document as a string (name is ignored).
> - FI: equivalent to F + I option.
> - FD: equivalent to F + D option.
> - E: return the document as base64 mime multi-part email attachment    (RFC 2045)

[Documentación](https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1)

[Referencia Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198949/how-to-send-the-file-inline-to-the-browser-using-php-with-tcpdf)